# How come I have superuser privileges without being in sudoers file

Tags: permissions, sudo

I've just installed Ubuntu and my user is a superuser which can execute commands with `sudo`. So I thought this user is added in `/etc/sudoers` file. But it seems it's not there:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The user info:

```
uid=1000(someuser) gid=1000(someuser) groups=1000(someuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),
30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
```

How did I get superuser privileges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are in the group `sudo`. To quote your sudoers file (I draw your attention to the helpful comment before the effective line):

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user is a member of `sudo` group.

As you can see in the `sudoers` file all members of the group have permissions to use `sudo`.